# celery systemd multiple services one delay not working

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, systemd

Help! I need the power of your collective consciousness! Here's the case.

I'm trying to build an NGINX/Gunicorn/Celery/RabbitMQ/Django server for several services. Each is a Django application below NGINX/Gunicorn, that's the easy part. One service, let's call it 'harvester', has some celery @shared_task and a celerybeat @periodic_task that launches it. The other service, 'factory', has only one @shared_task. The point is - when celerybeat launches 'harvester.tasks.harvesting', it sends the result to an API method of the 'factory' service. This method validates data, and if correct, launches the 'factory' task... like factory_task.delay(record)

And here goes the problem. While both daemons of the 'harvester' service work correct... the task of the 'factory' service is not launched at all. No records in the logs... no errors... all services run as usual...

Versions:

- **Ubuntu**: 16.04
- **Python**: 2.7.12
- **Django**: 1.10.6
- **Celery**: 4.0.2
- **Kombu**: 4.0.2
- **RabbitMQ**: 3.5.7

Here're config files:

**1. HARVESTER **

**1.1 /etc/systemd/system/celery-harvester.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=celery harvester daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
Group=group
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/harvester/config/celery.conf
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/harvester/project
# PIDFile=/var/www/harvester/socket/celery_harvester.pid
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} -Q ${CELERY_QUEUES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OP$
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} -Q ${CELERY_QUEUES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OP$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**1.2 /var/www/harvester/config/celery.conf**

```
# === CELERY HARVESTER ===

# Name of nodes to start (a single node, "or w1 w2 w3")
CELERYD_NODES="wh"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="harvester"

# Queues
CELERY_QUEUES="harvester"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--autoscale=8,1"

# PID&LOG
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/www/harvester/socket/celery_harvester.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/www/harvester/log/celery_harvester.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# === CELERY BEAT ===

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE="/var/www/harvester/socket/harvester-schedule"
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/www/harvester/socket/celerybeat_harvester.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/www/harvester/log/celerybeat_harvester.log"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

**1.3 harvester django celery settings**

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Sol/Moon'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'harvester'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('harvester', Exchange('harvester'), routing_key='harvester'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'harvester.tasks.parse_rss': {'queue': 'harvester'},
}
```

**2. FACTORY **

**2.1 /etc/systemd/system/celery-factory.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=celery factory daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
Group=group
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/factory/config/celery.conf
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/factory/project
# PIDFile=/var/www/factory/socket/celery_factory.pid
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} -Q ${CELERY_QUEUES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OP$
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} -Q ${CELERY_QUEUES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OP$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**2.2 /var/www/factory/config/celery.conf**

```
# === CELERY FACTORY ===

# Name of nodes to start (a single node, "or w1 w2 w3")
CELERYD_NODES="wf"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="factory"

# Queues
CELERY_QUEUES="factory"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--autoscale=8,1"

# PID&LOG
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/www/factory/socket/celery_factory.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/www/factory/log/celery_factory.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

**1.3 factory django celery settings**

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Sol/Fobos'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'factory'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('factory', Exchange('factory'), routing_key='factory'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'factory.tasks.parse_record': {'queue': 'factory'},
}
```

**=== IMPORTANT!!! ===**

I've already double-triple-checked all files permissions, users, groups. Also it's definitely not a RAM or disk-space case. The only thing that i found - sometimes 'factory' daemon worker writes some prints to */var/log/syslog*, and sometimes to *journalctl -xe*. But it doesn't write anything to its own log-file that is pointed in his config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem was somehow related to the routing system in Celery. Maybe I configured it the wrong way, but it seems to ignore the **CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE**, **CELERY_QUEUES** and **CELERY_ROUTES** options in Django settings.

A solution that worked for me is to get rid of them in settings, and provide them as options in the **@shared_task** decorator itself, like below.

```
@shared_task(default_retry_delay=20, max_retries=5, soft_time_limit=20, queue='factory', routing_key='factory')
```

Also, working on that I found that an **AUTOSCALE** option of the Celery workers is not a reliable option, cause sometimes it ends up loosing tasks, probably when they coincide with autoscaling by some timing...

More can be found here - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2682